# "which led to police issue an Amber Alert" [sic]

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> Budd, 43, is wanted in connection with the death of Justin Bird, 17,
>   and the abduction of his ex-spouse's 17-year-old daughter, **which led
>   to police issue an Amber Alert** for the girl yesterday. *([Jonas Budd, suspect in abduction and fatal shooting, located in Saskatchewan - CBC news Feb.19 2015](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/saskatchewan/jonas-budd-suspect-in-abduction-and-fatal-shooting-located-in-saskatchewan-1.2963459))*

Is **the bold part** grammatically right? or Is it supposed to be "**which led police to issue an Amber Alert**"?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo

Comment: I might join in the close voting on ELU, but not here on ELL. I can understand how a learner might wonder if this is a mistake, or a wording they simply haven't learned yet.

Comment: I do notice the main text is correct, it's merely the photo caption that has the incorrect wording.

Comment: @BCdotWEB  Yes you are right. They must have corrected it later on. When I posted my question on the morning of 19th, it hasn't yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.  The reporter was probably in a hurry, and made a mistake.  Either of the following options would be correct:

- which led police to issue an Amber Alert
- which led to police issuing an Amber Alert

Comment: ...although pedants will argue that the second option is still grammatically incorrect: [the gerund *issuing* cannot have a subject, but must instead take a possessive.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_with_a_specified_subject) The corrected second option is: *which led to the police's issuing an Amber Alert*

Comment: The second form may be grammatically incorrect, but nevertheless, it is commonly used, at least in my experience.